# MySQL Casting a VARCHAR as INT for search

Tags: mysql, casting, int, varchar

I'm trying to perform a numeric between search on a varchar field, where all rows are
pretty much int's anyway. I can't change the datatype of the row, since this is how this
particular program operates unfortunetly, I tried using this unsuccessfully

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_shipment_grid
WHERE CAST(order_increment_id AS SIGNED) 
BETWEEN 100073843 AND 100073504;
```

increment_id is actually varchar(50), so i've tried other ways to do this like

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_shipment_grid
WHERE order_increment_id >= '100073843' 
AND order_increment_id <= '100073504';
```

but i figure it won't work since I'm still trying to ambiguously search a varchar field.
any recommendations, and am I going down the right road trying to CAST the row as an INT in order to search? Thanks guys

Comment: Calling a function on a column in `WHERE` sounds like quite bad idea, as your query will stop using indexes on this column.

Comment: Is the fact that your start value is bigger than your end value a typo?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson it was, and also the reason the search didn't return correctly